# AppleScript error: 'Expected "else", etc. but found unknown token'

Tags: applescript

I'm new to AppleScript. The editor isn't giving me syntax highlighting so I'm a bit stuck with this error.

```
set exportPath to path to documents folder as text

with timeout of (30 * 60) seconds 
    tell application "Evernote"
        repeat with nb in every notebook of application "Evernote"
            set theName to the name of nb
            set matches to find notes "notebook:" & "\"" & theName & "\""
            set f to exportPath & theName & ".enex"
            export matches to f
            if (count of matches) > 0 then 
                set p to POSIX path of f
                do shell script "/usr/bin/gzip -f " & quoted form of p
            ￼end if
        end repeat 
    end tell
end timeout
```

When I click OK on the error the cursor position is changed to before the end in the end if line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some weird, unknown character just before `end if`.

Take that line out and re-type it and it will work.

```
set exportPath to path to documents folder as text

with timeout of (30 * 60) seconds 
tell application "Evernote"
    repeat with nb in every notebook of application "Evernote"
        set theName to the name of nb
        set matches to find notes "notebook:" & "\"" & theName & "\""
        set f to exportPath & theName & ".enex"
        export matches to f
        if (count of matches) > 0 then 
            set p to POSIX path of f
            do shell script "/usr/bin/gzip -f " & quoted form of p
        end if
    end repeat 
end tell
end timeout
```

Comment: When I do that then syntax highlighting starts working again! Weird. Thanks